# Sitecore upgrade System.Exception Message: Invalid object name 'Shadows'. Source: Sitecore.Kernel

Tags: upgrade

I am upgrading from `Sitecore.NET 8.2 (rev. 161221) to Sitecore 9.1 update-1`. I followed the sitecore guide to upgrading. As per the guide, I ran the database upgrade scripts on `master, web and core database`. The script contains the following:

```
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[Shadows]') AND type in (N'U'))
DROP TABLE [dbo].[Shadows]
```

After running the script there is a step to run the .update file which analyse all the changes. I am seeing lot of these errors in the analyze part:

```
Error installing 'addeditems/master/sitecore/templates/list manager/listoperation_{e83e0792-d9be-49d8-b7e2-80a6cc2d1836}'. More info


    Some of the installation operations cannot be performed.
    An exception occured when trying to install 'addeditems/master/sitecore/templates/list manager/listoperation_{e83e0792-d9be-49d8-b7e2-80a6cc2d1836}'.
    Details: System.Exception: Invalid object name 'Shadows'. ---> System.Data.DataException: 
Error executing SQL command: SELECT [TargetID], [ProxyID] FROM [Shadows] WHERE [ShadowID] = @proxyId ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 
Invalid object name 'Shadows'. at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) at
```

The database upgrade script has actually removed that table from a database. I am not sure then why package analyze step is complaining about this table missing from the database.